# How to run IntelliJ's Google App Engine Dev Server plugin in Java 8 mode

Tags: google-app-engine, intellij-idea, java-8, google-cloud-platform, intellij-plugin

I have a simple Google App Engine project that uses Java 8 and makes use of some of the previously restricted classes when GAE ran Java7.

Running the development server in maven (`mvn appengine:devserver`) works successfully and the restricted classes are loaded correctly.

However, running using the IntelliJ app engine plugin to run the application causes the old error of:

`Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.net.ProxySelector is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.`

How should the plugin be configured to run the application in the correct Java8 Mode?

---

Details:

- Java Version = 1.8.0_151
- App Engine SDK Version - 1.9.64
- appengine-web.xml has `<runtime>java8</runtime>` set.
- IntelliJ Version 2018.2.2
- VM Options set to `-Duse_jetty9_runtime=true -D--enable_all_permissions=true` due to this error https://github.com/sbt/sbt-appengine/issues/56

[image: IntelliJ GAE Runner plugin configuration screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although IntelliJ and all plugins were up to date, I just realised that Google released a new plugin for managing Google Cloud through IntelliJ.
Because the plugin is completely new it didn't get updated/installed automatically and it needs to be installed manually.

Installing the new version has resolved the issues, and the dev runner is now working correctly.

> **Installation**
>
> You can find our plugin in the Jetbrains plugin repository by going to IntelliJ -> Settings -> Browse Repositories, and search for 'Google Cloud Tools'.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-intellij#installation