# Intellij Keeps Telling Me "App Engine SDK path is not correct.'

Tags: google-app-engine

Trying to deploy my first Google Cloud Java app using Intellij. I've followed and read so many threads and have gotten absolutely nowhere on what is seemingly one of the simplest steps of getting this set up. I have installed gcloud CLI and followed the instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java-gen2/setting-up-environment). After installing, I run the commands 'gcloud components update' and 'gcloud components install app-engine-java'. I see the folder located in both 'C:\Users<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine' and 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine'. I installed as multi user after hours of trying to get the single user install working, so now I have both. When in Intellij I am creating a new Google App Engine project under Java EE, it asks to specify a Google app engine SDK. There are no options so I choose to select the path. I have tried both above paths and it only tells me 'App Engine SDK path is not correct'. What am I doing wrong?? The steps seem ridiculously simple and it just doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You stopped at the general google app engine folder

You need to specify the full path to the java-sdk folder, see the image in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52039478/how-to-run-intellijs-google-app-engine-dev-server-plugin-in-java-8-mode).